How to customize RequestSecurityToken Issuer?
I have this code to create a "RequestSecurityToken":
var request = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
         TokenType = "some:urn",
         AppliesTo = new EndpointReference($"some:other:urn"),
         Issuer = new EndpointReference("https://some.domain.net"),
         RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue
    };

and I found that the generated xml has the "Issuer" tag made like this:
<trust:Issuer>
    <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>https://some.domain.net/</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:EndpointReference>
</trust:Issuer>

The problem is that the SecurityTokenService expects the "Issuer" tag to contain only the "wsa:Address" tag (without the "EndpointReference" wrap):
<trust:Issuer>
    <wsa:Address xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        https://some.domain.net/
    </wsa:Address>
</trust:Issuer>

I already have an implementation of "IClientMessageInspector" to add some headers to the request message before sending it, but I didn't want to also change the request body in it.
I also tried to override the Issuer property in a custom class, but then it doesn't serialize the message correctly.
Is there another way to resolve this (beside changing the xml before sending it)?
Application uses .NET Framework 4.8

I think this post was helpful to you:How to get specific RequestSecurityToken serialization

You can try rewriting WSTrust13RequestSerializer.
The idea is to check if the element name is EndpointReference, and if so, replace it with the wsa:Address element.
public class CustomRequest : WSTrust13RequestSerializer
{
    public override void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer, string elementName, object elementValue, RequestSecurityToken rst, WSTrustSerializationContext context)
    {
       
        if (elementName == "EndpointReference")
        {
           
            string address = ((EndpointReference)elementValue).Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

           
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsa", "Address", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
            writer.WriteString(address);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        else
        {
            
            base.WriteXml(writer, elementName, elementValue, rst, context);
        }
    }
}

